# How long should I steam Artichokes?

Tags: cooking-time, steaming, artichokes

I know that it should steam until the leaves pull off easily. But how long does that take?

Answer (score 4):

I found steaming artichokes to require a very unpredictable about of time, and have fallen in love with the microwave method.

1. Cut off the stem so it can sit flat
2. Cut off a little of the top of the thistle.
3. Pour about 1 tablespoon or a few milliliters of water into the middle.
4. Wrap securely in plastic film
5. Microwave on high for about 10 minutes. Test the base for softness with a toothpick. Use about two minutes extra if needed.
6. When done, open the wrapping and carefully pour out any remaining water.

They can still be unpredictable, but at least the variation is a little less.

Comment: Great microwave idea. There are a few dishes that cook great in them, like Chinese style steam fish works perfectly in the microwave.